# PLSQL parse json list: JSON Scanner exception

Tags: json, plsql

I'm parsing a json feed but when I loop the json_list I get the following error:

ORA-20100: JSON Scanner exception @ line: 1 column: 33086 - string ending not found

Looking at the feed I'm unable to find anything out of the ordinary. It started to make me wonder if there's a character limitation.

my code is pretty simple..here are the relevant parts:

```
 DECLARE
   a_list       json_list;
   v_list       clob;
   obj_         json;
   .....
 BEGIN
  ....
  req := utl_http.begin_request (v_url,'GET');
  res := utl_http.get_response (req);
  utl_http.read_text(res, v_list);
  a_list := json_list(v_list);
  for i in 1 .. a_list.count loop
    obj_         := json(a_list.get(i)); 

    val_source   := obj_.get('source');
    val_date     := obj_.get('date');

    el_source  := val_source.get_string;
    el_date    := val_date.get_string;
  end loop;
  ...
 END;
```

Is there anything that I'm doing wrong? Or any hints out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out....

I read the data into a buffer string and basically worked on the data by chunks and then appended it to a clob.

```
 dbms_lob.createtemporary(p_res_clob, false);
 req := utl_http.begin_request (v_url,'GET');
 res := utl_http.get_response (req);

begin
  -- process the request and get the response:
  loop
    utl_http.read_text(res,l_buffer,32000);
    dbms_lob.writeappend(p_res_clob,length(l_buffer), l_buffer);
  end loop;
end;
a_list := json_list(v_list);
for i in 1 .. a_list.count loop
  obj_         := json(a_list.get(i)); 

  val_source   := obj_.get('source');
  val_date     := obj_.get('date');

  el_source  := val_source.get_string;
  el_date    := val_date.get_string;
end loop;
...
END;
```

Hope this helps someone who gets stumped :)